# ob_end_clean error with phpmailer

Tags: php, email, html-email, phpmailer

I'm trying to send a mail whit PHPmailer but get errors and don't know how to attack this problem.
I hope somebody can help me whit this.
(in the test phase this set-up works strangely enough)

I got this class which i call.  :

```
class Mailer{

protected $mailer;
public function __construct($mailer) {
    $this->mailer = $mailer;
}

public function send($template, $data, $callback){
    require_once 'core/init.php';
    $message = new Message($this->mailer);

    extract($data);

    ob_start();
    require $template;
    $template = ob_get_clean();
    ob_end_clean();

    $message->body($template);

    call_user_func($callback, $message);//callback message

    $this->mailer->send();
}
}
```

Here is the point where i try to mail, and as said before, in the test fase this works whit ob_end_clean.

```
require 'classes/PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
    $mailer = new PHPMailer;
    require 'core/mailsettings.php';
    $mail = new Mailer($mailer);

    $mail->send('mailtemplate/new_bid.php',['name'=>Input::get('name'), 'activation_code' => $randomString1,'servername' => $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"],'bid' => Input::get('bid'),'bidid' => $bidid, 'email' => Input::get('email')],function($m) {
                    $m->to(Input::get('email'));
                    $m->subject('Your input is in progress, please check your mail to activate.');
                });Redirect::to('index.php');
```

But when i try to send the mail I got an error from ob_end_clean.

> Notice: ob_end_clean() [ref.outcontrol]: failed to delete buffer. No buffer to delete

even if I try

```
 if (ob_get_length() > 0) { ob_end_clean(); }
```

as suggested here ([failed to delete buffer. No buffer to delete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14549110/failed-to-delete-buffer-no-buffer-to-delete)).

Is there something I'm doing wrong in the class Mailer??
Or is there a better way to construct the public function send????

please advice,
thank in advanced.

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: I noticed it :) and edited it, thanks Gerald

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are cleaning the buffer twice:

```
$template = ob_get_clean();
ob_end_clean();
```

The second call will throw your error because the first already deleted the buffer.

Comment: Almost right, the ob_end_clean() fails because ob_get_clean() also *deletes the buffer*

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be usefull and maybe the isseu, unfortenaly i can only try if this works tonight.I'll give it a try tonight.
@symcbean: I'm sorry but what do you mean? isn't your answer the same as from Gerald?

Comment: --> So what do you suggest?? remove ob_end_clean sins it has no valeu or do something totaly diffrent??

Comment: Quote [from the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-clean.php): `ob_get_clean() essentially executes both ob_get_contents() and ob_end_clean()`. Remove the second function, or replace the first with `ob_get_contents()`. It's up to you, the result is the same.