# How can I use an output buffer inside a foreach loop?

Tags: php, buffer

I am building a simple class that can generate html for my email body by a combination of a template include and an array of data that I extract inside an output buffer.

The problem is that when I run the method with the output buffer inside a loop (to create emails based on user information) I get the following error:

> ob_end_clean(): failed to delete buffer. No buffer to delete in ...
>   Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by ...

What do I have to change so it works both for a single email and inside a loop?

**Email class**

```
<?php
class Email {

   protected $_html;

   protected $_data;

   public function __construct( array $email_data = [] ) {
      $this->_data = $email_data;
      $this->generate_html();
   }

   protected function generate_html() {
      $template_path = 'path/to/email-template.php';
      ob_start();
      extract( $this->_data );
        include $template_path;
      $this->_html = ob_get_contents();
      ob_end_clean();
   }

   public send( $to = [] ) {
      mail( $to, 'Test email', $this->_html, ['Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8'] );
   }

}
?>
```

**Testing my code:**

```
<?php 
function send_test_email( $id, $to ) {
   $email_data = [
      'id'    => $id,
      'name'  => 'Joe',
      'price' => '30.00'
   ];
   $email = new Email( $email_data );
   $email->send( $to );
}

// Works
send_test_email( 122, 'joe@example.com' );

// Does not work
// ob_end_clean(): failed to delete buffer. No buffer to delete in
// Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by ...
foreach ( $users as $user ) {
   send_test_email( $user->id, $user->email );
}
?>
```

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14549110/failed-to-delete-buffer-no-buffer-to-delete

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld No, unfortunately I had already tried that

Comment: ob_end_clean() turns off the output buffering. Are you sure you don't mean ob_clean() ?

Comment: It would be better if you could get the template to build a string and return it rather than relying on output buffering.

Comment: https://3v4l.org/ALSkO You start buffering so shouldn't throw an error.

Comment: If you remove include $template_path; you don't get the error?

Comment: how does `$users` look like?

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld same error..

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld yes I did take a look, but I think this is not the way I would like to make it work. Because I then always have to start and clean the output around this method..

Comment: @NigelRen and how would you design that?

Comment: Mainly if you want something to be more modular, outputting something directly can be difficult to control (as you've found) so when building the template file, all it does would be build a string with the content you currently display and then leave it to the calling routine to do the actual work.  This can also help in testing, you can call a function and test the return value rather than messing with output.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @NigelRen do you have any template file builder pattern recommendations? Hold in mind that I need to use conditional logic inside a template.

Comment: @Robbert - I've updated with an alternative solution (I haven't tested it but it should work)

Answer (score 2):

Let's take a look at how output buffers work:

```
// Works
send_test_email( 122, 'joe@example.com' );

/*
    When you have executed send_test_email() above the method generate_html() is 
    executed and ob_start and ob_end_clean() is executed. This means that the output 
    buffer is initiated and stopped with ob_end_clean(). 

    When output buffer is ended it is sent to the client (browser).
*/

//If you do the same again...
send_test_email( 122, 'joe@example.com' );

/*
  ...this won't work because output buffer is sent to the browser. After this is done
  you are not able to modify header information. Because you cannot modify header 
  information you can not start a new output buffer either.

  That is why you get the error below:

  ob_end_clean(): failed to delete buffer. No buffer to delete in
  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by ...
*/
```

To solve this issue I would try something like this:

Move out `ob_start()` and `ob_end_clean()` *outside of the class* and remove them from the method `generate_html()`

```
protected function generate_html() {
    $template_path = 'path/to/email-template.php';
    extract( $this->_data );
    include $template_path;
    $this->_html = ob_get_contents();
}
```

Testing your code:

```
ob_start();
send_test_email( 122, 'joe@example.com' );

foreach ( $users as $user ) {
   send_test_email( $user->id, $user->email );
}
ob_end_clean();
```

**UPDATE**
You could solve this without messing around with output buffers, something like:

```
protected function generate_html() {
    $template_path = 'path/to/email-template.php';
    extract( $this->_data );

    //requires the template file to have a return to able to store the
    //content in a variable
    //
    //Look at $foo = include 'return.php'; 
    //at https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php
    $this->_html = include $template_path; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 protected function generate_html() {
      $template_path = 'path/to/email-template.php';
      ob_start();
      extract( $this->_data );
        include $template_path;
      $this->_html = ob_get_clean();  //use ob_get_clean()  instead of ob_get_contents();
   }
```

Hope it will help you

Comment: Tried it, but still got the error: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by ...

Comment: check in your code is there any single space before <?php open ?